# PWA's (progressive web apps) not working in full screen mode on desktop?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Following [a super simple PWA tutorial](https://medium.com/james-johnson/a-simple-progressive-web-app-tutorial-f9708e5f2605), I'm interested in having an **app in full screen mode** while installed on desktop.

You can see the code here: [github](https://github.com/jamesjohnson280/hello-pwa)

And the live page here: [hello world pwa](https://jamesjohnson280.github.io/hello-pwa/)

If you install it with chrome: 
[image: install progressive web app in chrome]

Everything works, except it looks like this: 
[image: pwa not working in full screen on desktop]

**I've included `"display": "fullscreen",` in my manifest.json.** as explained here: [pwa manifest docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest#display)
[image: the manifest is recognized as full screen but does not work in full screen mode]

So whats wrong then? **How to make this app go full screen for real?**

Comment: I have the same issue in my first PWA. Does anybody know a cure for this?